# alternatives to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to send emails?

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp

I'm looking for a .NET assembly I can use from within ASP.Net 3.5 to send one or two emails at a time.

I've looked at **System.Net.Mail.MailMessage** but the resulting communication between the script and the mail server uses ESMTP and I would *really* like to avoid that.

The emails to be sent are as simple as can be : not encrypted; not html; etc.

Priority is ease of deployment so don't want to have mess with IIS, Exchange etc.

Comment: What exactly is it about SMTP that you're trying to avoid? And, FYI, it's the `SmtpClient` class that sends the mail message and this determines the protocol.

Comment: are there other protocols except SMTP that can help you sending email ?

Comment: I took a look out of interest and there doesn't seem to be anyway to force the .net mail to use old smtp (RFC 821) but I doubt you really need to anyway.  Looks like on MSDN System.Net.Mail is based on RFC 2821 which specifies that if the host doesn't recognise the EHLO (extended HELO) greeting then the client should issue HELO and proceed using only RFC821 standard commands.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : I'm deploying an app to an environment I've previously worked in (with classic ASP) and where there's no need to identify yourself to the mail servers (as long as SMTP is used). I would like to continue to not have to authorise myself but with ESMTP you have to. The amount of meetings I would have to attend in order to do the whole authorisation things makes me inclined to stick with a 'no-auth' approach.

Comment: @user861114 I've previously used SMTP in this environment (see my comment above to John Saunders) so I would like to stick with that - thanks for your question.

Comment: @BenStephens OK that's very interesting information. Possibly I've misintpreted what I've seen it, system.net.mail, doing to date. Would you mind letting me have a URL for where you saw that (a little dubious about MS sticking to RFC's !). Anyway I will have another look - thanks for your comment. In the meantime if anyone else has a straightforward alternative I'm still interested

Comment: Now that I know you're just trying to avoid authenticating can garauntee you there's no reason not to just use System.Net.Mail... you can just do a plain email with a FROM and a TO with it no worries.   None of my websites authenticate with SMTP (since it's localhost and port is not exposed to WAN).  MSDN article is here, point about the RFC used is in the Remarks toward the bottom http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Comment: @BenStephens - would you be able to put the substance of your two comments into an answer so I could accept it please ?

Comment: Ah sorry, assume you've been able to get everything going?  Posted as answer, thanks for prompting me :D

Comment: @BenStephens Yes I was thanks, and thanks to the other commenters as well for their input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look through MSDN and there doesn't seem to be a way to force System.Net.Mail to use older smtp standards (RFC821) however you shouldn't need to.

According to the remarks section of the following article, System.Net.Mail implements RFC2821 which states that if a host doesn't recognise the EHLO (or extended HELO) greeting then the client should issue HELO and proceed using only commands available in RFC821.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

As we discussed in the comments since you're just trying to avoid using authentication can garauntee you'll be able to use the System.Net.Mail library without needing to authenticate.